# I have installed python on linux and i want to use pycharm on my windows desktop

Tags: python, pycharm

I have installed python 3.6 on my linux machine(Linux vm is text mode) I need to install pycharm and access the python installed on linux from my windows dekstop

Comment: Are you saying you want to deploy something from your desktop to your laptop?

Answer (score 1):

Frankly, I am not really sure why you want to do this, so you might want to rethink.

Since you have  a headless Linux VM, I would personally recommend installing X-Widows or Wayland.

If you have good reasons not to do that, there is still a very simple solution. All VM systems that I am aware of allow you to share a directory/folder between host and guest, so that's the easy way to go.

You don't say which VM you are using (please rememberer GIGO - the more information that you provide us, the better that we will be able to help you).

I will take a guess that you are using the most popular, and free, which is VirtualBox. You will find detailed instructions, with screenshots, [here](https://helpdeskgeek.com/virtualization/virtualbox-share-folder-host-guest/) showing how to share a folder between your Windows Host and your Linux Guest VM.

Should you be using something other than VirtualBox, the principe is the same, and you can either poke around in the "Settings" Menu or Google for e.g `VMware share folder between host and guest`.

Btw, congratulations on choosing PyCharm - the community edition is without doubt the best Python IDE there is  - plus it is free, even for commercial use.

Welcome aboard :-)

Comment: There's a large number of libraries that don't even compile on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Mawg's answer would be my recommendation and will give you the most productive workflow for development, including being distractions-free. :-) It is what I've done.

But if you still want the distractions, you can install an SSH client that includes an X-Server, such as [MobaXTerm](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/), and when you run the command-line to launch any X-Windows piece of software (such as PyCharm), the display driver will tunnel the X-Windows protocol through the SSH connection and will give you a local window managed by the local WM. It's kinda slow over WAN, but pretty damn seamless over LAN or loopback.